# mono and libgdiplus - libgdi not found

Tags: mono, gdi+

Whenever my application calls into libgdi, I get the following:

```
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus --->
System.DllNotFoundException: /opt/mono-3/lib/libgdiplus.so
     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup(ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
     at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x000cc] in /build/buildd/mono-3-opt-3.2.3/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/gdipFunctions.cs:127
```

Okay, fair enough: I need to have libgdi in a spot mono can find it.  I was reasonably certain I had made and installed it previously, so I started by looking at `ldconfig` to see where it is:

```
libgdiplus.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so.0
libgdiplus.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so.0
libgdiplus.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
libgdiplus.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so
```

I naively thought that if the library was identifiable in `ldconfig`, mono would be able to find and use it.  Is that not the case?  Is there an ambiguity between `/usr/local/lib` and `usr/lib` that needs resolution?

Anyhow, I *think* I can tell mono to look at `/usr/lib/libgdiplus.so` using `dllmap` like the following:

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="/usr/lib/libgdiplus.so" os="!windows"/>
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/usr/lib/libgdiplus.so" os="!windows"/>
<dllmap dll="/opt/mono-3/lib/libgdiplus.so" target="/usr/lib/libgdiplus.so" os="!windows"/>
```

... but being a neophyte, I'm not certain that's correct.  Mono still claims it cannot find libgdi at runtime, and I'm just about out of ideas.

Can one use `dllmap` in this way?  And if so, where am I going wrong?  If not, can I get a suggestion on what to try next?

For what it's worth, I'm attempting to run using Mono 3.2.4 from MonoDevelop 4.2.3.

Comment: Did you try to create a symlink /opt/mono-3/lib/libgdiplus.so pointing to /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so?

Comment: @jariq I _just_ got done giving that a try - it works, but I'm still curious why it won't work as-is.  If you want to offer it as a solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. My guess why it didn't work without a symlink: Library is being loaded dynamically with dlopen() and there is hardcoded path to /opt/mono-3/lib/libgdiplus.so. It may have been hardcoded during the configuration phase of mono building. But it is just a guess. I would have to check mono sources to confirm it.

Comment: I was wondering if I ran the libgdi autogen against the `/opt/mono-3/lib` directory if it would work, but was too gunshy to pull the trigger.  I might try it on a scorchable VM later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a symlink /opt/mono-3/lib/libgdiplus.so pointing to /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so.